# Symfony2 - Routing error online only, not locally

Tags: symfony, routes

I appreciate you taking the time to read my problem.  As stated in the title, I am able to have this code run error-free on my local XAMPP server, but when I upload it, I get an error.  My prod.log online gives an error that the route cannot be found.

The code in question is below:

```
/**
 * @Route("features/{id}", name="features", defaults={"id" = 0})
 * @Template("FluffyBundle:Page:features.html.twig")
 */
public function indexAction($id)
{
```

So what I am trying to accomplish is that if you come to mydomain.com/features, the "id" value is 0, and my code will know this means not to display a specific article.  However, if you come to mydomain.com/features/280, it will pull the article with the ID of 280 from my database.  Now, coming to the features page with no ID specified causes no issue online or offline.  It's only when I attempt to access mydomain.com/features/### that I am prompted with a 500 error, and the prod.log saying no route found.  Locally, it pulls the selected article from the database, just not online.

Any help in understanding why the exact same code online does not work, but offline it does, would be greatly appreciated.  I'm sure there is something I'm missing or overlooking, but I can't figure it out.  As an additional note, I run the code locally in both the dev and prod environments, with no errors being thrown that I can see.

Comment: did you clear the cache (maybe even `rm -rf app/cache/*`)? symfony makes heavy use of caches in production mode to speed up the application!

Comment: To be clear: You are testing your page locally in dev mode (`app_dev.php`) and prod mode (`app.php`), and both work. And if you are running it on the server (I guess prod mode) it doesn't work anymore? What happens if you run it on the server in dev mode?

Comment: I actually cleared the cache numerous times, and even completely deleted and reuploaded my site. The issue persists online only.

Comment: When I try to run it on the server in dev mode, I get an error saying that I cannot access the dev mode file.  It works in prod environment locally, and dev environment, but online in prod mode with a fresh upload of files with no cache gives errors.

Comment: First of all check your prod.log (app/logs/prod.log) on the server and second add your IP to app_dev.php in in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array('127.0.0.1', 'fe80::1', '::1', '33.33.33.1', ADD_YOUR_IP_HERE)).

Comment: As I mentioned in my comment, I did check the prod.log, and it says route not found.  This does not happen in the prod version locally.  I will try app_dev change you suggested to see what it says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I consider this issue close.  It turns out I used the wrong table name in one section of an entity, and it caused Symfony to break in a really strange way.  The error didn't reflect that, but upon fixing the table name issue, the problem is resolved.